# DDOS - Google Cloud Instance vs. Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, ddos, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am planing to launch a little Website but i am afraid of DDOS Attacks and the additional costs there would be charged.

I read that Amazon EC2 is not charging the inbound http requests?
What is about the Google Cloud instance?

**What could you advise me?**

Comment: In regards to the billing part of your question, inbound traffic to GCE is not charged. Nevertheless HTTP requests will generate responses and outbound traffic. You can find the details on network egress price  [in this  document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#network)

Answer (score 3):

This link can be interesting for you ''Best Practices for DDoS Protection and Mitigation on Google Cloud Platform'' :

> https://cloud.google.com/files/GCPDDoSprotection-04122016.pdf